# What does 'Image file pass' in scalpel output mean?

Tags: data-recovery

I've accidently fully formatted an external hard drive after cutting a large folder from my Ubuntu desktop and pasting it on the external hdd.
Since I **fully** formatted the hdd, I ran scalpel in order to find the files that were cut from the desktop with the following command:

```
scalpel /dev/sdb4 -o /media/myusername/F4D27EB9D27E8022/undel/
```

Scalpel was able to recover many files, but then it stopped because the destination didn't have any more storage space.  The last lines in the terminal were:

```
Image file pass 2/2.
/dev/sdb4:   1.9% |                                                                                     |    4.4 GB --:--ETAError writing to file: /media/myusername/F4D27EB9D27E8022/undel/mov-13-6/00161878.mov -- Operation not permitted
Scalpel was unable to write output files and will abort.
This error generally indicates that disk space is exhausted.
```

I tried googling "Scalpel Image file pass" in order to understand in what stage scalpel got stuck, in order to decide if to run it again or not (it ran for 6 days before it got stuck) but I didn't find any place that explains Scalpel's terminal output.

Here is the full terminal output:

```
Scalpel version 1.60 Written by Golden G. Richard III, based on Foremost 0.69.

Opening target "/dev/sdb4"

Image file pass 1/2.
/dev/sdb4: 100.0% |*************************************************************************************|  232.3 GB    00:00 ETAAllocating work queues...
Work queues allocation complete. Building carve lists...
Carve lists built.  Workload:
art with header "\x4a\x47\x04\x0e" and footer "\xcf\xc7\xcb" --> 0 files
art with header "\x4a\x47\x03\x0e" and footer "\xd0\xcb\x00\x00" --> 0 files
gif with header "\x47\x49\x46\x38\x37\x61" and footer "\x00\x3b" --> 618 files
gif with header "\x47\x49\x46\x38\x39\x61" and footer "\x00\x3b" --> 24616 files
jpg with header "\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10" and footer "\xff\xd9" --> 22319 files
png with header "\x50\x4e\x47\x3f" and footer "\xff\xfc\xfd\xfe" --> 40149 files
bmp with header "\x42\x4d\x3f\x3f\x00\x00\x00" and footer "" --> 53045 files
tif with header "\x49\x49\x2a\x00" and footer "" --> 2343 files
tif with header "\x4d\x4d\x00\x2a" and footer "" --> 3475 files
avi with header "\x52\x49\x46\x46\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x41\x56\x49" and footer "" --> 341 files
mov with header "\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x6d\x6f\x6f\x76" and footer "" --> 776 files
mov with header "\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x6d\x64\x61\x74" and footer "" --> 6857 files
mov with header "\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x77\x69\x64\x65\x76" and footer "" --> 760 files
mov with header "\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x73\x6b\x69\x70" and footer "" --> 240965 files
mov with header "\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x66\x72\x65\x65" and footer "" --> 302809 files
mov with header "\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x69\x64\x73\x63" and footer "" --> 726 files
mov with header "\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x70\x63\x6b\x67" and footer "" --> 116 files
mpg with header "\x00\x00\x01\xba" and footer "\x00\x00\x01\xb9" --> 224251 files
mpg with header "\x00\x00\x01\xb3" and footer "\x00\x00\x01\xb7" --> 36322 files
fws with header "\x46\x57\x53" and footer "" --> 10599 files
doc with header "\xd0\xcf\x11\xe0\xa1\xb1\x1a\xe1\x00\x00" and footer "\xd0\xcf\x11\xe0\xa1\xb1\x1a\xe1\x00\x00" --> 45859 files
doc with header "\xd0\xcf\x11\xe0\xa1\xb1" and footer "" --> 46604 files
pst with header "\x21\x42\x4e\xa5\x6f\xb5\xa6" and footer "" --> 0 files
ost with header "\x21\x42\x44\x4e" and footer "" --> 81 files
dbx with header "\xcf\xad\x12\xfe\xc5\xfd\x74\x6f" and footer "" --> 5 files
idx with header "\x4a\x4d\x46\x39" and footer "" --> 9 files
mbx with header "\x4a\x4d\x46\x36" and footer "" --> 39 files
wpc with header "\x3f\x57\x50\x43" and footer "" --> 17241 files
htm with header "\x3c\x68\x74\x6d\x6c" and footer "\x3c\x2f\x68\x74\x6d\x6c\x3e" --> 20733 files
pdf with header "\x25\x50\x44\x46" and footer "\x25\x45\x4f\x46\x0d" --> 269 files
pdf with header "\x25\x50\x44\x46" and footer "\x25\x45\x4f\x46\x0a" --> 441 files
mail with header "\x41\x4f\x4c\x56\x4d" and footer "" --> 0 files
pgd with header "\x50\x47\x50\x64\x4d\x41\x49\x4e\x60\x01" and footer "" --> 0 files
pgp with header "\x99\x00" and footer "" --> 11304213 files
pgp with header "\x95\x01" and footer "" --> 8299173 files
pgp with header "\x95\x00" and footer "" --> 9088602 files
pgp with header "\xa6\x00" and footer "" --> 67419516 files
txt with header "\x2d\x2d\x2d\x2d\x2d\x42\x45\x47\x49\x4e\x20\x50\x47\x50" and footer "" --> 64 files
rpm with header "\xed\xab" and footer "" --> 1879447 files
wav with header "\x52\x49\x46\x46\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x57\x41\x56\x45" and footer "" --> 800 files
ra with header "\x2e\x72\x61\xfd" and footer "" --> 59 files
ra with header "\x2e\x52\x4d\x46" and footer "" --> 57 files
dat with header "\x72\x65\x67\x66" and footer "" --> 1040 files
dat with header "\x43\x52\x45\x47" and footer "" --> 587 files
zip with header "\x50\x4b\x03\x04" and footer "\x3c\xac" --> 1369115 files
java with header "\xca\xfe\xba\xbe" and footer "" --> 159846 files
max with header "\x56\x69\x47\x46\x6b\x1a\x00\x00\x00\x00" and footer "\x00\x00\x05\x80\x00\x00" --> 0 files
pins with header "\x50\x49\x4e\x53\x20\x34\x2e\x32\x30\x0d" and footer "" --> 0 files
Carving files from image.
Image file pass 2/2.
/dev/sdb4:   1.9% |     |    4.4 GB --:--ETAError writing to file: /media/myusername/F4D27EB9D27E8022/undel/mov-13-6/00161878.mov -- Operation not permitted
Scalpel was unable to write output files and will abort.
This error generally indicates that disk space is exhausted.
```

I'll be very thankful for any hint!

Comment: How could you format a filesystem with cut and paste? Did you use dd?

Comment: There was a miss-understanding.  I cut from my computer's hard drive (from linux's desktop) and pasted in the external hdd.  Then I formatted the external hdd.   I am now trying to retrieve the data from the computer's hdd.